# Open link on file excel on Browser by code JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, excel

I have file excel 100 link, I want to open link on Browser.

My code:

```
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const open = require('open');

const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
const filePath = 'D:\\3.py\\link1.xlsx';

workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath)
    .then(() => {
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    const links = worksheet.getColumn('B').values;

    links.forEach(link => {
        open(link, { target: '_blank' });
    });
  });
```

But error:
TypeError: Expected a `target`
at open (D:\3.py\node_modules\open\index.js:229:9)

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace code

```js
open(link.hyperlink, { target: '_blank' });
```

with it